# How to embed non hosted images into an email signature HTML

Tags: html, css, image, html-email

I need to embed images into an email signature, the images arent hosted on a website but I can't just reference images from a folder as this needs to work for 50 people. I've tried using URI for base 64 but gmail and a few other email clients won't open the images. I've heard about inline attatching them but don't know how to go about it.

Comment: Essentially, you do need to host them somewhere

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Google's embedded images as follows: You save your images to your google photos. Go to one of your images, then, click "share". Click on "create link". Copy that link and paste it in the text field on this site (Google
's embedded image site) : https://www.labnol.org/embed/google/photos/   Click "generate", and the embedded link for your image will appear. This is what I use for my HTML-Emails. Unfortunately, it is tedious if you have many images, but it works.

Comment: How does that work with non-gmail emails?

Comment: It works the same in all email providers. You are only using different links in your HTML.